# Can this C# generic code be simplified and just one type be passed in?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

The following code from my team mate works:

```
 public T Get<T, V>(V repo, string pk, string rk)
            where T : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
            where V : IAzureTable<T>
        {
            try
            {
                var item = repo.GetPkRk(pk, rk);
                if (item == null) throw new Exception(); return (T)item;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _ex.Errors.Add("", typeof(T).Name + rk + " does not exist");
                throw _ex;
            }

        }
```

Calling code:

```
var account = base.Get<Account, IAzureTable<Account>>(_accountRepository, pk, rk);
```

Can it be simplified. The only type variable here is "Account" and I am wondering if the T and V types could be combined into one as V depends only on T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
public T Get<T>(IAzureTable<T> repo, string pk, string rk)
{
    ...
}
```

then

```
var account = base.Get<Account>(_accountRepository, pk, rk);
```

you could possibly even get away with

```
var account = base.Get(_accountRepository, pk, rk);
```

if the compiler can infer the parameter type from `_accountRepository`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'm marking this as accepted as your last comment saved me from having to enter in <Account>.

Answer (score 5):

Since the only place that `V` appears is in the signature, I'd have thought you could change it to:

```
public T Get<T>(IAzureTable<T> repo, string pk, string rk)
        where T : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
```

But I don't have sample code handy to test this.

Answer (score 3):

```
public T Get<T>(IAzureTable<T> repo, string pk, string rk)
        where T : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
```